# Usar free() sem o malloc()?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Pode ocasionar algum problema em usar o `free()` em um ponteiro que não foi alocado com `malloc()` alem da desnecessidade em si?

```
void funcao (int par)
{

    char  *palavra;

    if(par%2 == 0)
    {
         palavra = malloc(3*sizeof(char));
         strcpy(palavra, "par");
    }

    free(palavra);  
    palavra = NULL;  
}
```

isso e só um exemplo, seu sentido ou implementação não importam.

Comment: Dê uma exemplo de uso assim.

Comment: pronto, não tem sentido algum, só para dar exemplo do que quis dizer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No exemplo mostrado **pode** causar problema. É chamado de [*dangling pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

O `free()` está atuando na variável `palavra` que não foi inicializada. Ou seja, em C tem um valor nela, você não tem ideia de que valor é esse, variará em cada execução da aplicação gerada. Ele tentará liberar a memória apontada por esse endereço. Se der sorte pode apenas falhar e nada acontecer ou pode liberar algo que estava alocado e não devia. Pode acontecer algo desastroso e até desalocar coisas completamente fora do que se espera, já que até o tamanho da alocação pode ser considerado erroneamente pelo `free()`. A informação é virtualmente aleatória.

Em C temos que tomar muito cuidado. Um desses cuidados é sempre inicializar a variável. Isso faria com que o `free()` errado não causasse problemas, ainda que o código não estaria estritamente correto. O ideal é não deixar um `free()` livre assim (não resisti :) ). Vai que um dia alguém mude alguma coisa e ele passe ser um problema mesmo em casos onde não era inicialmente.

Comment: foi bem esclarecedor, confesso que tenho algumas duvidas sobre alocação e endereçamento de memoria em C, que diference de outras linguagens que não preciso me preocupar com isso, mas no entanto, ela se torna bem didático, obrigado

Answer (score 6):

Seguem algumas observações:

> **1** - É uma boa prática inicializar os ponteiros para NULL ao declara-los, um ponteiro sem a inicialização adequada pode apontar
>   para algum endereço de memória inválido (dangling pointer ou ponteiro
>   selvagem);
>
> **2** - Segundo o padrão, quando `free()` recebe um ponteiro NULL, nenhuma ação é tomada, ou seja, não há nenhum problema em passar um
>   ponteiro NULL para `free()`;
>
> **3** - Quando você alocar memoria para acomodar strings, não se esqueça de incluir um byte para o terminador '\0'.

Segue uma sugestão de melhoria para o seu código:

```
void funcao( int par )
{
    char * palavra = NULL;

    if( par % 2 == 0 )
    {
        palavra = malloc( (3 + 1) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy( palavra, "par" );
    }

    free(palavra);  
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Lucas, pode sim ocasionar vários problemas, pois quando a função free, for liberar a área de memória que em tese deveria ter sido alocada com a função malloc e associada a um ponteiro, este não estará apontando para uma área controlada pelo compilador, desta forma, os resultados podem ser inesperados. Tome cuidado e boa sorte.

Comment: Mas não foi alocada com o `malloc()`. O compilador não controla áreas de memória.

Comment: Só trocar compilador por "código runtime do C usado pelo compilador" . A resposta faz sentido  sim.